# spring boot(3.1.0) with OKTA SAML authentication enters into infinite loop

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, okta, okta-api

I am configuring OKTA SAML 2.0 authentication with Spring boot application(v3.1.0) and ending up with infinite loop.
Here is my config code:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    RelyingPartyRegistrationResolver relyingPartyRegistrationResolver = new DefaultRelyingPartyRegistrationResolver(this.repository());

    Saml2MetadataFilter filter = new Saml2MetadataFilter(relyingPartyRegistrationResolver, new OpenSamlMetadataResolver());

    OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider samlProvider = new OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider();
    samlProvider.setAssertionValidator(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultAssertionValidator());
    samlProvider.setResponseValidator(OpenSaml4AuthenticationProvider.createDefaultResponseValidator());
    
    ProviderManager providerManager = new ProviderManager(samlProvider);
    http.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable());
    http.saml2Login(saml2 -> {
        saml2.authenticationManager(providerManager);
    }).addFilterBefore(filter, Saml2WebSsoAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize.requestMatchers("/responseFromSAML").permitAll().requestMatchers("/favicon.ico").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated());
    
    http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS));
    http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext.securityContextRepository(new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository()));
    return http.build();
}

@Bean
RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository repository() {
    RelyingPartyRegistration registration = RelyingPartyRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("regID").assertionConsumerServiceLocation("https://sp-url/sso/saml")
            .assertingPartyDetails(party -> party.entityId("http://www.okta.com/regID").singleSignOnServiceLocation("https://sp-url/sso/saml")
            .singleSignOnServiceBinding(Saml2MessageBinding.POST).wantAuthnRequestsSigned(false)
            .signingAlgorithms((sign) -> sign.add(SignatureConstants.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_RSA_SHA256)))
            .build();
    return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(registration);
}
```

##### Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping("responseFromSAML")
public String home(@AuthenticationPrincipal Saml2AuthenticatedPrincipal principal, Model model) {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    System.out.println("authentication: " + authentication);
    System.out.println("principal: " + principal);
    return "home";
}
```

Response from OKTA SAML: `we are receiving samlResponse(which we can see in samlTracer)`

Can anyone please help?

I tried to print 'principle' which is coming as null and `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` is giving 'anonymous'

Comment: I wrote a tutorial about Spring Boot and SAML with Okta and Auth0. Maybe it'll help? https://developer.okta.com/blog/2022/08/05/spring-boot-saml

Comment: Hi @MattRaible, I already went through your tutorial guide and without 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' it throws  "Factory method 'relyingPartyRegistrationRepository' threw exception with message: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect" and after adding it, it again goes into infinite loop.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or proxy that's preventing an outbound connection?

Comment: @MattRaible, I don't think so because we are able to send request to Okta Idp and receiving samlResponse(which we can see in samlTracer and HttpServletRequest).

Comment: Any update on above issue or any input required from my side?